# Market percentage growth per timeframe

Tags: markets, growth, market-decline

Is there an indicator that shows price growth for a particular market item (stock, commodity, forex) per timeframe? I mean like price growth/decline in last 24 hours or other time period?

Comment: It's easy to find closing prices for stocks or indexes, then divide current by the date a day/week/month ago. Is this what you're looking for or one thing more complex?

Comment: Yes, it is that easy, but I thought there would be already an indicator for this introduced. Such a simple thing. If I want to plot it to a chart, have to do it myself probably.

Comment: Sites like Google and Yahoo offer that data plotted for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is an indicator called the "Rate of Change (Price)". It provides a rolling % change in the price over the period you have chosen.

Below is an example showing a price chart over the last 6 months with a 100 day Rate of Change indicator below the price chart.

[image: Rate of Change (Price)]